# What is the word for "turning a noun into an adjective"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a specific name or term for words that are the adjective form of nouns? Like "salty" from "salt", "Freudian" from "Freud", "glossy" from "gloss", etc.? What about adjective forms of verbs "loathsome" from "loathe"? Or verb forms of nouns like "to telephone"?

Comment: Do you mean other than "Derivative Word Forms"?

Comment: I'm so confused... What am I supposed to be doing again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [*Introduction to the Grammar of English* - Rodney D. Huddleston (1984)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=adjectivalisation&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

> The most straightforward type of **adjectivalisation** involves affixation, as in the formation of *heroic*.

Comment: +1 Now there's a word you don't hear every day. This may, in fact, be the only time in my life I will ever hear it. ;-)

Comment: @Jim If you’re lucky, that is.

Comment: @Jim: Go on! Indulge yourself! There's also [adverbialisation](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SM2MSU43uy4C&pg=PA242&lpg=PA242&dq=%22serve+to+adverbialise+only+true+nouns%22&source=bl&ots=9tBkUq-YI7&sig=9XnGSmgCQbuNJRURumOMuBXfDT4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TJQxUIK-KeOj0QX93IDoDA&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22serve%20to%20adverbialise%20only%20true%20nouns%22&f=false) if you fancy getting really down and dirty!

Comment: Is there a hypernym for those words as well? That would really make my day :)

Answer (score 3):

One uses *derivational morphology* to ***derive*** an adjective from a noun, creating derivative forms.

Although you don’t always have to. You can sometimes just use it attributively.