# Adjective for an activity that is not condoned

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for an adjective that could be used to describe an activity that is generally frowned upon, although not necessarily illegal. Or if it is indeed unlawful, then it should be a "soft" illegality, in the sense that people enforcing the law would recognize such activity as illegal but would probably "let it slide."

The closest word I have found is *illicit*, but it does not entirely reflect what I'm trying to get across.

Comment: How about "proscribed"?

Comment: *Frowned upon* - you said it yourself.

Comment: Taboo.  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/taboo

Comment: Illicit, prrhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

**dubious**

> adj. ...
>
> 2. of doubtful quality or propriety; questionable: a dubious compliment.
>
> [[Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K
>   Dictionaries]

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dubious)]

or

**questionable**.

Answer (score 0):

If informal usage would work for you:

**[shady](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shady)**

> 2 informal Of doubtful honesty or legality:
>
> *Because she did not suspect a shady deal was brewing, when she found out the loan was approved, she signed on the dotted line.*

And the synonyms: [fishy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fishy#fishy__6), [murky](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/murky#murky__7) and [dodgy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dodgy)

Comment: Unfortunately, I would prefer to keep to formal usage. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @AlBenoit You are welcome :-). For formal usage Edwin Ashworth's answer is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S. an infraction is the lowest legal level of a crime and is commonly considered less than a crime. "Ah, that's nothing, man--an infraction. You won't even get a slap on the wrist." Now what's the word for turning a noun into an adjective?

Comment: Often used with "minor", i.e., "minor infraction", but by definition a violation of law nonetheless. And btw, it's "adjectivalisation": http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/what-is-the-word-for-turning-a-noun-into-an-adjective